# Alphanumeric cell format (using custom format)

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I want to display an alphanumeric code in this format:

A/DDDDD/DDDD

Where A is letter and D is digit. If there are less digits, a leading 0 should be displayed.

Example:
W/1/1 displays: `W/00001/0001`
Z/12345/1234 displays: `Z/123345/1234`
W/123/123 displays: `W/00123/0123`

The value in cell should persist in given format (with out leading 0).

Comment: You cannot format alphanumeric values in excel; only numeric.

Comment: my foul. changed.
thx

Answer (score 1):

This Macro will do it for you.

This will create the result in a new column. So, my version looks at my column A which contains the in-correctly formatted content (EG `W/1/1`). I have nominated to have column B display the new result.

So, make sure you have the developer ribbon and draw a button from the Controls pane. When it asks you assign macro, click New. Paste the following into the new Window over the top (deleting everything that was there and assuming that your macro name is Button1_Click)

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim cellRow As Integer
cellRow = 1           'UPDATE THIS IF YOUR FIRST ROW DOESN'T START AT ROW 1

For Each c In Range("A1:A2") ' UPDATE THIS FOR ALL CELLS
Dim splitString() As String
splitString = Split(c.Value, "/")

Dim result As String
result = splitString(0)

If (Len(splitString(1)) = 5) Then

    result = result + "\" + splitString(1)

Else

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 5 - Len(splitString(1))
    result = result + "\"
    For x = 0 To i - 1
        result = result + "0"
        i = i + 1
    Next x
        result = result + splitString(1)
End If


If Len(splitString(2)) = 4 Then
    result = result + "\" + splitString(2)
Else

    Dim j As Integer
    j = 4 - Len(splitString(2))
    result = result + "\"
    For y = 0 To j - 1
        result = result + "0"
        j = j + 1
    Next y

result = result + splitString(2)
End If



Range("A" + CStr(cellRow)).Value = result ' UPDATE FROM A IF YOU DON'T WANT IT TO OVEWRITE EXISTING CONTENT 
cellRow = cellRow + 1

Next
End Sub
```

Now, this will crash if you have empty cells or anything which doesn't exist in the formatted you specified, eg `WT\456789456/12345AL` will not perform as desired

But, this doesn't really care about the value being Alpha or numeric, it just expects the initial value to be the desired character type.

**Update**

The code can be made shorter as per @SeanCheshire excellent comment

A shortcut to make a 5 character zero padded string would be

```
right("00000" & splitstring(1),5)
```

No loops or extra variables needed. Your entire string construct would be

```
splitstring(0) & "\" & Right("00000" & splitstring(1), 5) & "\" & Right("00000" & splitstring(2), 5)
```

Comment: I can not have this displayed two times due to print accurate formatting.  
My current solution is to have 3 cells:  
`| W|/00012|/0002` but customer wants it in one field.

Comment: @Saram In that case, you can just overwrite it... Just change the 4th from last line to an A instead of a B. I updated my code and this will do it for you. However, this is dangerous so I do suggest you make sure you have a back up first!

Comment: A shortcut to make a 5 character zero padded string would be `right("00000" & splitstring(1),5)` - no loops or extra variables needed. Your entire string construct would be `splitstring(0) & "\" & Right("00000" & splitstring(1), 5) & "\" & Right("00000" & splitstring(2), 5)`

Comment: does it fulfill this: "The value in cell should persist in given format (with out leading 0)."?

Comment: @DaveRook I did not test it, because I can read code and I noticed that it can be problem. Now I tested it, and I confirm. This does not work as expected.

Comment: What does that even mean? "the value in cell should persist..."

Comment: When you type `W/1/1` it should be displayed as: `W/00001/0001`, but when you back to edit it again the original 'W/1/1' value should appears. Just like numeric custom formatting behavior.
I hope I'm clear, but please forgive me my English, I'm not native.

Comment: Right... (@saram, your English is excellent). You can't do this without some form of persistence. So, I think you'd have make the code copy the initial value, stick it in another work sheet and have another button to 'revert' back (or at least, revert back on close).